# Get column data one-by-one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Wondering how to retrieve all the data in a column of my database table one by one. (Say retrieve next value after every 30secs).

Comment: Normally, we retrieve data from database tables with a `SELECT` statement.Execute the query to materialize a resultset, then fetch rows from the resultset. Typically we retrieve rows from the resultset as quickly as possible, and not hold query results open longer than necessary.) How would you satisfy this requirement without needing to wait 30 secs?

Answer (score 1):

By sending one-by-one for every 30sec following query

```
SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
```

Where to get next value you increase OFFSET (in above e.g to 4). The LIMIT means how many values you wanna get (in your case 1). The OFFSET means starting position of cursor/row in table. Working example [here](https://paiza.io/projects/6ekTktUW8w1DDzn11Kt7Mw?language=mysql)

However more efficient way of read data is reduce number of queries and increase LIMIT

Comment: Kietczewski I have a very large table with rows nearly 12M. So adjusting LIMIT  and OFFSET to read from `row=1` 1 to `rows=117051923` is time consuming (and may probably skip some intervals unnoticed). Is there a way to write the query so the LIMIT and OFFSET are determine by the database engine?

Comment: @arilwan this is separate question find it or ask on stackoverflow